# using python like php with nginx

Tags: python, nginx, php

We are currently using nginx as a web server along with PHP-FPM as the php application service. We have a small application which needs to be built but must use Python3. Is their a similar option to use for Python?

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 will probably be the limiting factor for you.  I'm not completely up-to-date on WSGI and Python 3 since I work with 2.7, but [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) was one of the few supporting it last time I checked.

Update: I have just learned that [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) is now Python 3 compatible.

That said, once you've found your WSGI or FastCGI-compatible framework, you just need to set up an application container like [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) or FastCGI, and then configure nginx to talk to it on the specified socket while serving the static content.  This is probably very similar to what you're already doing with PHP-FPM.

uWSGI nginx example:

```
location = /testapp {rewrite ^ /testapp/; }
location /testapp { try_files $uri @testapp; }
location @testapp {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /testapp;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try uwscgi.   Easy to config and high performance.

Answer (score 0):

The framework [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) is a webserver itself that runs Python3 code. What you can very easily do is to configure nginx to serve static part of your site and to route all requests for dynamic parts to a cherrypy server.

It's also easy with this approach to have nginx serving [memcached](http://memcached.org/) data generated by Python code to get even faster execution.

Answer (score -1):

the best solution for what you are looking for is WebPy http://webpy.org/